# Setting up Relays in Windows

Tags: windows, networking, relay

I'm trying to setup a pivoting relay with netcat on Windows, replicating a scenario easily possible by using pipes in Linux.

Assume machine A can route to machine B and machine B can route to machine C.  If machine A needs to route to machine C, we can setup a relay on machine B which can pivot data back and forth for us using command redirectors and spl filetype pipe.

Assume:

- machine C has `nc -nlvp 3306 -e cmd.exe`
- machine A has `nc -nlvp 80`

IF machine B was Linux we could have done

```
mkfifo pipe
nc -nv 127.0.0.1 80 0<pipe | nc -nv 127.0.0.1 3306 1>pipe
```

so on machine B if we do

```
nc -nv 127.0.0.1 80 0<&4 | nc -nv 127.0.0.1 3306 1>&4
```

Per [this site](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true), I should be able to achieve what I can with Linux, but unfortunately it is not working.

Comment: That's really a networking/OS question, not a security one - better to ask on SuperUser?

Comment: What is not working exactly? I might be nit-picking, but I assume C can route back to B and A, too? Have you tried running tcpdump or wireshark on B to see where the packets stop?

Comment: @Auditor - will migrate this through to SuperUser - they may be able to help you better than we can, so follow the new link and you can easily set up an account over there.